# Run text() of Xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am going through selenium practice where xpath validates in [firefox xpath extesion](https://code.google.com/p/xpathchecker/) but not in python selenium.

e.g. go to [here](http://www.hotleathers.com/Front-Printed-T-Shirts-C1232.aspx?s=OrderBy%20ASC&&v=all) and apply xpath `//span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]` it works in firefox extension but not in selenium expression like `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]")`

Exception i am facing

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      Debug Probe, prompt 17, line 1
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 270, in find_elements_by_xpath
        return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 739, in find_elements
        {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector //span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
    InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple returning record:

```
driver.get("http://www.hotleathers.com/Front-Printed-T-Shirts-C1232.aspx?s=OrderBy%20ASC&&v=all")

returnText = []
returnText = self.driver.execute_script("var iterator = document.evaluate(\"//span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]\", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null ); var arrayXpath = new Array();  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext(); while (thisNode) {arrayXpath.push(thisNode.textContent);  thisNode = iterator.iterateNext(); }    return arrayXpath;")

for item in returnText:
    print item
```

Pure Javascript code is:

```
var iterator = document.evaluate('//span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]", documentNode, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

  while (thisNode) {
    alert( thisNode.textContent );
    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  } 
}
catch (e) {
  dump( 'Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e );
}
```

Comment: This js for array populating with elements will not work for the site https://www.google.com/ncr#q=chiropractors%2BNew+York,+NY&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl     it gives truncated business name for xpath `//div[@class='_pl _ki']/descendant-or-self::text()[1]` like only `Broadway `  not `Broadway Chiropractic & Wellness`

Comment: You selected index [1]

Comment: Ah! `[2]` selects reviews e.g. `4 reviews etc` but fact is, all text after `<wbr>` is excluded like `Chiropractic & Wellness` i mentioned earlier!

Answer (score 1):

Selenium evaluate only web elements. text() function returns an object. the solution is to execute xpath in javascript function and return its value into variable. for ex, for python:

```
returnText = []
returnText = driver.execute_script("return  document.evaluate(\"//span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]\", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;")

for item in returnText:
    print item
```

Comment: Above script returns a single value but is there any option for list.

Comment: do you mean Select-option list?

Comment: I mean getting all the html elements  in that page (see question) that satisfies that xpath.

Comment: you can append /text() to your xpath in whatever element you want.

Comment: Yeah, How can i grab all the values that satisfy that xpath expression like http://imgur.com/E8OmhnE

Comment: when you print returning value, what do you see?

Comment: It returned G
M
S
1
3
2
3 just one item not all.