# How to perform Xpath looping?

Tags: selenium, xpath

While working on selenium,I have the xpath

```
//tbody[@id='se-tbody-result']//tr[3]//a
```

I want to loop `tr[value]` from `tr[3]` to `tr[20]`.

Comment: XPath loops automatically. If you write `a/b`, it loops over all children selecting `a` ("if name is 'a'"), and for each `a` it loops over all children to select the matching elements `b`. What you need is to limit the loop on certain positions: `tr[position() >= 3 and 20 >= position()]`.

Answer (score 5):

Such xPath would return you values from tr[3] til tr[20]

```
//tbody[@id='se-tbody-result']//tr[position()>=3 and position()<=20]//a
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple for loop in java works for me

```
    public void sample() {
    for (int i=3; i<=20; i++) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody[@id='se-tbody-result']//tr["+ i + "]//a"));
    }
```

Comment: Why would you complicate your imperative code if without string concatenation, a trivial XPath expression suffices to select positions 3-20?

Comment: @Abel I wouldn't call that a trivial XPath expression. I've read a LOT of Selenium questions and many answers involving XPath and this is the first one I've seen using `position()`.

Comment: @jeffc, this answer already uses position(); if the predicate is only numeric it is short for `position() =X`, where X is an expression returning a number. Its syntax is explained in about every xpath tutorial I've seen, but if you never needed it, you may not have encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below if in python-

```
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='se-tbody-result']//tr")
for i in trs[3:20]:
    my_a = i.find_element_by_xpath(".//a")
    print my_a.get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: Same here, why making it so hard if all you need is one trivial XPath expression to get the same? Besides, this does not filter 3-20 as requested by the OP.

Comment: I edited the code, xpath with position() function returns text node selenium can not handle this ( complex JS help may be sought for this-  deails at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866302/run-text-of-xpath-in-selenium) so better to grab immediate parent of text node and get text from it using get_attribute function of selenium or others

Comment: No, using `position()` has no effect on what type of node you return. In this case, it would be an element. If you were to end your expression with, say, `tr[position() > 3]/a/text()` you would be returning text nodes. But you end with `a`, so you return element nodes. Also, be aware that your code will give strange, unpredictable results on nested tables (but that is true for all solutions in the question thread).